# How to find the difference between two lists including duplicate elements

Tags: kdb

Please help me to write a function to find difference of two lists including duplicate elements.
Lists are not equal lengths.

```
q)l1:1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 6 7
q)l2: 1 1 2 4 5 6
q)l1 except l2
3 3 7      /4 is missing in result
/expected result : 3 3 4 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group` function helps here.

```
{
  e: (count each group x) - (count each group y); 
  e: (where e>0)#e;
  raze (value e)#'(key e)
}
```

On the `1st` step we check how many numbers are in both lists and subtract counts.
Then we keep only numbers with positive counts and convert `number->count` dictionary into desired list.

Comment: Hi Anton, I tested your function with different input, it seems it is not returning excepted result. q)l1: 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 6 7 1  and result is 1 3 3 4 7 instead of 3 3 4 7

Comment: Seems right, you have three 1's in the first list, one of them should stay.

Comment: It's my mistake. Thank you Anton

Comment: `{ where (-). count@''group each (x;y) } [1 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 6 7; 1 1 2 4 5 6]`

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
q){$[any found:x in y;x _:first where found;x]}/[l1;l2]
3 3 4 7
```

It loops through the items in l2 to see if there is any in l1 and drops it.